# Unable to link to Localhost using Curl

Tags: python, curl, flask, webserver, localhost

I have used commands like curl 127.0.0.1:5000 and curl localhost:5000. Both the commands leading me to curl:(7) connection refused by the server error.
What is the significance of digit 7 there, and how can i fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html):

> **CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)**
>
> Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

It would appear that nothing is listening on `localhost:5000`,
your service is not actually running.

For what it's worth,
your command is correct.
If Flask was running and listening on port 5000,
then both `curl localhost:5000` and `curl 127.0.0.1:5000` would work.
Check the console where you started Flask.
It should print a message like this, if it's indeed running:

> ```
> * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/
> ```